# Why do bosons have 0 energy in the ground state?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, pauli-exclusion-principle

When looking at an ideal boson gas, it was described that at T = 0K, all the of the particles in the gas will be at the ground state, which  I understand. What I don't see is why ground state is at E = 0. Electrons in their ground state have some energy. Is this energy linked with the fact bosons don't obey paulis exclusion principle?

Comment: Yes. At zero temperature, all bosons occupy the single-particle mode which has momentum zero, and hence the total kinetic energy is zero. This ignores interactions, of course.

Comment: Why is the ground state for electrons not the same? I understand that not all of them can occupy the ground state but those that do still have some total energy?

Comment: If the single-particle Hamiltonian allows a state that has zero energy, then at most **one** fermion can occupy this state (this is the Pauli exclusion principle, and applies to electrons since they are fermions). The other fermions must occupy other states, even at zero temperature.

Comment: But remember, absolute values of energy are not meaningful, it is differences in energy that are measurable. We just set the zero point of energy to the lowest state we have.